# MIDI devices not visible anymore after removing services/devices

Tags: windows, services, device-manager, midi

To reduce the DPC latency of my laptop I played around disabling/removing various drivers and services (without success though), possibly including.

However, I now notice that my MIDI devices do not show up anymore in a program (GigPerformer, which I think is generic, not related to this specific software application).

When I connect a device both directly or via a USB hub, they show in the device manager (see picture), but they do not show up in GigPerformer.

Does anybody have a clue which device/service I need to reinstall/activate again or how to solve this problem?
Probably I accidentally removed a USB or MIDI driver/service.

Note that a connected USB stick and/or a mouse (to the USB hub) is fully working.

I tried reinstalling the MIDI devices and USB devices/hub, without any change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is a generic solution, but what helped with me was reinstalling audio interface (Behringer UMC 204HD 192k in the screen shot). The strange thing that this device was working correctly.

After that the MIDI devices were recognized in applications as well.